# querySelector, getElementById on div Inner HTML not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, express

Let say I have an ejs file with a nav bar containing a-tags of classes. Anytime each a-tags is click I do an http request to a server which response with a html code which I then set to be an innerHTMl of a div. The problem I am facing is that I can't do no queryselectors, get the elements or even do an event listeners on the html elements of the response HTML code. Is there a way to get this to work, because I really needed those to work.

The External javascript file that I used is below:

```
    var arr = this.id.split('-')
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
        document.querySelector('#nav-' + arr[1] + "-" + arr[2]).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
     }
 };
     xhttp.open("GET", "/basic" + arr[1] + "-" + arr[2], true);
     xhttp.send();
 })
```

Comment: is the status 200 and readyState 4? Are there errors?

Comment: Yes the above code works it’s just that I can’t do any query selector or even listeners on the elements in innerHTML or the div. it’s like they ain’t there

Comment: xhttp is not available there. It is because of the scope of the function. Try again with a hard coded string and see if there's an update as a sanity check. Or use `this.responseText`

Comment: The update part works, it actually set the innerHTML of the selected div to the response text of the request.

Comment: I got the example from here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: there a really good vid on debugging javascript here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtsvMRxmfGA the `debugger` keyword would really help here to understand what is available and what is not

Comment: That’s what I used and it works but doing a select on the page with the response text doesn’t do anything. Let say the response text contains a paragraph with a class name someClass, after the response my page will look something like this <div class=“class”> <p class=“someClass”></></div>, then if I try to do a query selector with class someClass it doesn’t do anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217934/discussion-between-jmp-and-user8628552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using using axios and append instead of innerHTML and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just to recap from our conversation, here is an example to compare with. Though to answer the question about why we can't use `xhttp.responseText`, that value is not available within the scope of the function. What's concerning is that the live example here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp shows using `xhttp` but then their live example uses `this`. `this` is assigned to the XMLResponse object. not sure why that is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object and fetch example</h2>
    <script>

        const URL = 'https://httpbin.org/get';

        function fetchExample() {
            let result = fetch(URL, { method: 'GET'});
            result.then((response) => {
                response.json().then((body) => {
                    document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(body); 
                });
            });
        }

        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
            xhttp.send();
        }

    </script>

    <div id="demo">
        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content using XMLRequest</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="fetchExample()">Change Content using fetch</button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is an example that I found here that makes some more sense
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response#Example

```
var url = 'somePage.html'; //A local page

function load(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      callback(xhr.response);
    }
  }

  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send('');
}
load("https://httpbin.org/get", console.log)
```

**Response**

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Origin": "https://developer.mozilla.org", 
    "Referer": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5f13bbc1-eaa2b0bc28697b24aca2db94"
  }, 
  "origin": "72.73.17.37", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Comment: Every seems to work except selecting or querying any of the element in the load html page.

Comment: what is the query and what is the DOM's contents at the time when the response is resolved? Seems like if that's the case, then either the query is invalid or the element doesn't exist in the DOM at that time.

Comment: @user8628552 were you able to get this working? If my answer helped could it be marked correct to help searches from other people?

Comment: can you provide the DOM and the query used? Not the parameterized string passed but the literal string value?